# support kerberos constrained delegation using SSPI for multiprocess

Tags: sspi, kerberos-delegation

I need to support Kerberos constrained delegation for our C++ HTTP server product on Windows using SSPI.

For a single process server, the follow workflow can be used and I have a working prototype.
  1) Call AcquireCredentialsHandle
  2) Call AcceptSecurityContext
  3) Call ImpersonateSecurityContext
  4) Do delegation
  5) Call RevertSecurityContext

However, the C++ HTTP server has a master process and a worker process. Both processes run on the same machine and use the same service account, and each client request can come from a different user. The master process can handle SPNEGO and Kerberos authentication using AcquireCredentialsHandle and AcceptSecurityContext, but it has no knowledge of which resource it needs to delegate, only the worker process has the knowledge. 
Which SSPIs can I use to forward the client's security context to the worker so that the worker can do impersonation/delegation?

Seems one possible solution is to get client's identity in the master, transfer that to the worker; then in the worker use LsaLogonUser and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser. However, since LsaLogonUser allows logon without password, our security expert is strongly against the use of it.

SSPI also has ExportSecurityContext and ImportSecurityContext, but the documentation is very vague and not sure if it can address my use case. Since the ImpersonateSecurityContext documentation says it "allows a server to impersonate a client by using a token previously obtained by a call to AcceptSecurityContext (General) or QuerySecurityContextToken.", seems I can't call ImpersonateSecurityContext after ImportSecurityContext.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is get a handle to a token in the parent process and duplicate it into the child process.

You do it this way:

In the parent process call `ImpersonateSecurityContext` as you normally would. This will set your identity. Then call `QuerySecurityContextToken` to get a handle to the token of that identity. Once you have the handle call `DuplicateHandle`, but where the target process is a handle to the child process. The returned `lpTargetHandle` is a locally referenced handle in the *target* process (the child). You will some how need to transfer this value to the target process.

Once the child process has the handle value you can call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` passing the handle value. At this point the local identity should be the user in question and any outbound calls will use that when creating the new context.

Keep in mind though that the child process will need the SeImpersonatePrivilege.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! I will give it a try.

Comment: Update: I have a working prototype using the workflow Steve mentioned. Thanks Steve!

Comment: I upvoted a couple of times. However since I am a new user (just registered for this question), I got a message saying it's recorded but will not be counted :-(

Comment: We have a new requirement to support Kerberos constrained delegation for SQL server using ODBC and JDBC. This means in the child process, we need to put the ODBC/JDBC connection call between ImpersonateLoggedOnUser/RevertToSelf. Does ODBC on Windows use SSPI? If yes, ODBC should work fine. But JDBC uses JGSS which by default can't access LSA. Microsoft has a sample program for JDBC constrained delegation which uses "protocol transition". Is this the only option if we want to support constrained delegation for JDBC on Windows process?

Comment: Here is the link to Microsoft sample program for JDBC constrained delegation: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/eea5de2079a21676653be451983cb6212af81739/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/KerbAuthentication.java