# Logical workflow steps for CreateProcessAsUser to ImpersonateLoggedOnUser and DuplicateHandle all to run a command as the user?

Tags: c#, winapi, kerberos, sspi

Coming from

[Windows C# Is there a way to create a new process with the Kerberos ticket of parent process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379058/windows-c-sharp-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-new-process-with-the-kerberos-ticket)

[support kerberos constrained delegation using SSPI for multiprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51735041/support-kerberos-constrained-delegation-using-sspi-for-multiprocess/51795116#51795116)

I'm trying to copy Kerberos credentials from one process to another to invoke a remote command. Steve has been very helpful, but I'm a little confused on how to create a child process, load it up with the proper credential handles, and impersonation, then get a hold of the same child process to execute the actual command since the call to DuplicateHandles requires the child process to exist first.

My question is, how do I get the Child Process to execute the command I initially intended for it to do as CreateProcessAsUser with impersonation?

Code so far:

```
var CurrentIdentity = ((WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Token;

IntPtr parentHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

CloneParentProcessToken.QuerySecurityContextToken(ref CurrentIdentity, out parentHandle);
IntPtr parentProcessHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

//Create Child Process as User
IntPtr childProcessHandle = CreateProcessAsUser();

IntPtr lpTargetHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

//Duplicate parent security handle into child
if (CloneParentProcessToken.DuplicateHandle(parentProcessHandle, parentHandle, childProcessHandle, out lpTargetHandle,
    ProcessUtility.TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, true, (uint)0x00000002))
{
    int childHandleProcessID = CloneParentProcessToken.GetProcessId(lpTargetHandle);

    IntPtr newChildProcess = ProcessUtility.OpenProcess(ProcessUtility.ProcessAccessFlags.All, true, childHandleProcessID);
    IntPtr newProcessAccessTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
    if (ProcessUtility.OpenProcessToken(newChildProcess, ProcessUtility.TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, out newProcessAccessTokenHandle))
    {
        //Impersonate the user in the new child process
        if (CloneParentProcessToken.ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(newProcessAccessTokenHandle))
        {
            //newChildProcess is pointer to child process with token and impersonation
            Process child = Process.GetProcessById(childHandleProcessID);

            //Have child process execute???
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since the call to DuplicateHandles requires the child process to exist
>   first.

You could set `hTargetProcessHandle` as current process, and `bInheritHandle` as true, so that the duplicate handle can be inherited by new processes created by the target process.
Then pass the new token to child process through IPC.

Comment: Thanks @Drake Wu - MSFT. Do you know how I could get the phContext necessary for QuerySecurityTokenCkntext from WindowsIdentity?